# Сортировка в csv Python по значениям в колонке с последующей записью каждую отличающуюся строку/строки в отдельный файл

Tags: python, сортировка, csv

Я в python новичок и гуглить старалась, но понять не могу.
Есть большой массив данных, который нужно рассортировать сначала по одному параметру с созданием подфайла, а потом с записью в отдельные файлы по другому признаку, но не избирательно, а обязательно не теряя порядка из исходного файла.

Comment: Файл поместится в память (RAM)?

Comment: Должен по идее.

Comment: Да все вроде для одного вопроса достаточно. 
Грубо говоря, сначала из файла нужно раскидать все в подфайлы по первому параметру от 1 до 13, а из этих подфайлов создать еще подфайлы, но тут уже нужно группировать их по определенному параметру и очередности. То есть, если у меня 
blocked |
blocked |
neutral |
blocked | то создавать из этого три файла, а не два. (Да, вы правы насчет отдельных вопросов, не подумала)

Comment: Понимаю, что тут стоит банальный цикл юзать, но не могу понять как.

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных задач идеально подходят модули [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) и [Dask DataFrame](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) (если объем данных не умещается в памяти [`RAM`]).

Пример:

**создание случайного набора данных:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 20  # число строк

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'grp': np.random.randint(3, size=N), 
  'status': np.random.choice(['blocked','neutral'], N),
  'val': np.random.rand(N)
})
```

получился следующий DataFrame:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
    grp   status       val
0     0  blocked  0.376250
1     0  blocked  0.795588
2     0  blocked  0.136974
3     1  blocked  0.309903
4     0  blocked  0.248737
5     2  neutral  0.978573
6     1  neutral  0.867362
7     2  blocked  0.384664
8     0  neutral  0.835107
9     1  blocked  0.307241
10    2  neutral  0.492961
11    2  blocked  0.395527
12    2  blocked  0.350670
13    2  neutral  0.027203
14    2  blocked  0.569344
15    2  neutral  0.898701
16    0  neutral  0.217991
17    1  neutral  0.410668
18    0  blocked  0.700303
19    2  neutral  0.208480
```

сохраним его как CSV файл:

```
df.to_csv('d:/temp/data.csv', index=False)
```

удаляем переменную `df`:

```
del df
```

---

**Решение:**

разбиваем CSV на отдельные CSV (чтобы в каждом CSV находилось только одно значение `grp`):

```
(pd.read_csv('d:/temp/data.csv')
   .groupby('grp')
   .apply(lambda g: g.to_csv('d:/temp/grp_{}.csv'.format(g.name), index=False)))
```

---

**Отступление - обзор технологий**

Для решения подобных задач подходят следующие модули/технологии:

1. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) - ограничен объемом памяти на одном компьютере/сервере
2. [Dask DataFrame](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) - основан на Pandas умеет разбивать данные на партиции и обрабатывать объемы данных не влезающих в память (сбрасывает часть данных на диск - аналог своппинга используемого в файловых системах)
3. [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) - горизонтально скалируемое (путём добавления узлов кластера) кластерное решение для обработки огромных объемов данных. Поддерживаемые языки: `Scala`, `Java`, `Python`, `R`

[Сравнение и рекомендации](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/spark.html?highlight=spark) - в каких случаях еще можно использовать [Dask DataFrame](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) или уже пора переходить на [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/)

Comment: Наверное, "гуглить старалась",  глагольная форма женского рода побудила дать такой подробный ответ))

Comment: @0xdb, просто мне нравятся задачи связанные с обработкой и анализом данных ;-)

Comment: Большое спасибо :3
Получилось и без панды заставить все работать, но попробую пересмотреть.